# Check Cordova Version from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

Is there any way to check from Javascript what version of Cordova an app is running?

**Why I ask:**

We've upgraded our Cordova from 2.8 to 4.0.2 and the *new* Cordova JS file does not work with the *old* Cordova Android code.  We want to force the user to upgrade their app (to in turn update their Cordova Android version), however, we need to detect that they're on the old version first.

**Why device.cordova won't work:**

It seems that the old Cordova JS code never initializes because it can't communicate with the new Cordova Android code.  So the plugins, such as the *device plugin* are never loaded.  We get a message in the console stating:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: now the simplest solution is this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/65476892/1243247

### Manual way

I made a functional hook script which I stored at `hooks/setVersion.js`. I just tested it now and it works (just in Android, for iOS you just need to replicate the `wwwDir`)

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var wwwFileToReplace = 'index.html'

var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = function (context) {
  var projectRoot = context.opts.projectRoot
  const wwwDir = path.join(projectRoot, 'platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www')

  var configXMLPath = 'config.xml'
  loadConfigXMLDoc(configXMLPath, (rawJSON) => {
    var version = rawJSON.widget.$.version
    console.log('Version:', version)

    var fullfilename = path.join(wwwDir, wwwFileToReplace)
    if (fs.existsSync(fullfilename)) {
      replaceStringInFile(fullfilename, '%%VERSION%%', version)
      console.log(context.hook + ': Replaced version in file: ' + path.relative(projectRoot, fullfilename))
    } else {
      console.error('File does not exist: ', path.relative(projectRoot, fullfilename))
      process.exit(1)
    }
  })
}

function loadConfigXMLDoc (filePath, callback) {
  var fs = require('fs')
  var xml2js = require('xml2js')
  try {
    var fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'ascii')
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser()
    parser.parseString(fileData.substring(0, fileData.length), function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
      } else {
        // console.log("config.xml as JSON", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
        console.log("File '" + filePath + "' was successfully read.")
        callback(result)
      }
    })
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

function replaceStringInFile (filename, toReplace, replaceWith) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')

  var result = data.replace(new RegExp(toReplace, 'g'), replaceWith)
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, result, 'utf8')
}
```

You have also to add in config.xml

```xml
<hook src="hooks/setVersion.js" type="after_prepare"/>
```

This script replaces the text `%%VERSION%%` in a file with the app version from config.xml, so you can have in your `index.html` file something like

```html
<html data-appversion="%%VERSION%%">
```

and in your JS

```
const version = document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-appversion");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `device.cordova` to get the current version of Cordova.

[Appropriate documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.cordova)

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize now I should have added more information about why this solution doesn't work for me...I'll update the question now.

Comment: Out of interest, are you using the default webview, or Crosswalk (or something similar)?

Comment: We're using the default Cordova webview, yes.

Comment: Alright, are you testing on an emulator? If so, are you using a livereload plugin to do so.

Comment: No, we're deploying to a device and using weinre to debug it remotely.

Comment: @DranoMax I assume you're putting the deviceready event listener after the inclusion of the Cordova JS file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87035/discussion-between-dranomax-and-chris-thomson).