# Cordova Hook should run only if --release is added in build command

Tags: cordova, ionic2, hook

I have a Cordova hook that executes after execution of build command. And one hook which executes before build command is executed.

I want it to executes only if --release attribute is added in build command.

Is it possible? As I am doing something in hook (i.e. changing version code of builds.) which I want to do only for release builds.

Please ask if something is unclear to you.

Comment: i have wrote a similar hook earlier but not exactly the same. That was to parameterize the app id to install facebook plugin. You can follow the similar sample to address. These links should help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304156/in-my-cordova-app-how-do-i-get-the-version-string-i-defined-in-the-config-xml/42650842#42650842 and https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Hooks May be in your case you gotta set release attribute as environment variable before every run

Comment: I think using Target env variable is what I need.

Comment: you are right. That should do the trick for you. Posted the answer. Cheers

Comment: SET TARGET=i && ionic cordova build ios --device --release

Comment: above commmand says there is no SET : command found

Comment: even run without && but still same error

Comment: set is the normal windows command we use to add env variable. https://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm

Comment: I am on mac system

Comment: check this post for non windows based solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml/38475946#38475946

Comment: u got it through?

Comment: Yes you can add in your answer that on mac there is no need to write set just (TARGET=a ionic cordova build ios ....) will work

Comment: updated the answer. Please accept and vote. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a similar hook sometime back but not exactly the same. That was to parameterize the app id to install facebook plugin. You can follow the similar approach to address your issue too.

These links should help you out - [SO post on hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304156/in-my-cordova-app-how-do-i-get-the-version-string-i-defined-in-the-config-xml/42650842#42650842) and [sample hook github repo](http://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Hooks). May be in your case you gotta set the release attribute as environment variable before every build instead of passing it as an build attribute. Hope it helps.

UPDATE: For mac OS, you can set environmental variables in the user directories `.bash_profile`